# Django не определеят STATIC_ROOT в settings.py

Tags: python, django, path, static

Пытаясь разобраться с загрузкой файлов в Джанго, понял, что views.py не получает значения, присвоенные в settings.py, касательно STATIC_ROOT и STATIC_URL. Но при этом значение STATICFILES_DIRS views.py получает, но получает насколько я понимаю не верное значение.

settings.py

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ""),]
```

urls.py

```
urlpatterns = [url(r'get_object/$', views.get_object, name = 'get_object'),]
```

views.py

```
def get_object(self):
   # static_files = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS
    static_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT

    if static_root:        
        path = static_root    
    else:
        path ='No object'

    return HttpResponse(path)
```

Django возвращает мне 'No object'. Если прописываю во views.py вместо static_root, static_files,

```
def get_object(self):
    static_files = settings.STATICFILES_DIRS
    # static_root = settings.STATIC_ROOT

    if static_files:
        path = static_files
    else:
        path ='No object'

    return HttpResponse(path)
```

Django дает 'C:/music/'. Как предполагаю ответ не верный.
Но мне необходимо получить STATIC_ROOT

Comment: Проверь еще раз путь:
`STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")]`

Comment: да, проблема была в том, что у меня в проекте было в settings.py. Спасибо за помощь!